# Neo4j server CPU Spike to 90% once the data folder size increases to 50 MB

Tags: neo4j, cpu

Neo4j server CPU spikes up to 90% (and higher) as the node size increases to 50 MB. Initially the CPU is well under 15% and suddenly spikes to 90% once a certain size limit is reached. I have turned off the logs as well.

Here is my server configuration:

- c4 x large instance
- 4 vCPU
- 7.5 GB memory

Here is the neo4j size configuration:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=40M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=40M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=150M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=70M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=30M

keep_logical_logs=false
keep_logical_logs=3 days
```

Below is the heap size and JVM configuration:

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=800
wrapper.java.maxmemory=800

wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:NewRatio=3
wrapper.java.additional=-d64
wrapper.java.additional=-server
wrapper.java.additional=-Xss2048k
wrapper.java.additional=-XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Here are the contents of `message.log`:

```
    12:45:12.943+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_VERSIONS START ---
     12:45:12.944+0000   Store versions:
     12:45:12.944+0000   Store versions:
     12:45:12.944+0000     NeoStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     SchemaStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     NodeStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     RelationshipStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     RelationshipTypeStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     LabelTokenStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     PropertyStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     PropertyIndexStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     StringPropertyStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000     ArrayPropertyStore v0.A.1
     12:45:12.944+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_VERSIONS END ---
     12:45:12.944+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_ID_USAGE START ---
     12:45:12.944+0000   Id usage:
     12:45:12.944+0000   Id usage:
     12:45:12.945+0000     SchemaStore: used=1 high=0
     12:45:12.945+0000     NodeStore: used=17545 high=17544
     12:45:12.945+0000     RelationshipStore: used=21105 high=21104
     12:45:12.945+0000     RelationshipTypeStore: used=1 high=0
     12:45:12.945+0000     LabelTokenStore: used=0 high=-1
     12:45:12.945+0000     PropertyStore: used=38777 high=38776
     12:45:12.945+0000     PropertyIndexStore: used=43 high=42
     12:45:12.945+0000     StringPropertyStore: used=106 high=105
     12:45:12.945+0000     ArrayPropertyStore: used=1 high=0
     12:45:12.946+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for NEO_STORE_ID_USAGE END ---
     12:45:12.946+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for PERSISTENCE_WINDOW_POOL_STATS START ---
     12:45:12.946+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for PERSISTENCE_WINDOW_POOL_STATS END ---
     12:45:12.946+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles START ---
     12:45:12.946+0000   Disk space on partition (Total / Free / Free %): 8318783488 / 2957176832 / 35
    Storage files: (filename : modification date - size)
     12:45:12.947+0000     neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 76.00 B
     12:45:12.947+0000     active_tx_log: 2015-05-09T12:43:00+0000 - 11.00 B
     12:45:12.947+0000     tm_tx_log.1: 2015-05-09T12:43:00+0000 - 32.73 kB
     12:45:12.947+0000     neostore.propertystore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 1.52 MB
     12:45:12.947+0000     neostore.relationshipstore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.948+0000     tm_tx_log.2: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 0.00 B
     12:45:12.948+0000     neostore.schemastore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.948+0000     neostore.labeltokenstore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 0.00 B
     12:45:12.948+0000     neostore.nodestore.db.labels: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 68.00 B
     12:45:12.948+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.949+0000     index.db: 2015-05-07T22:38:23+0000 - 479.00 B
     12:45:12.949+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.index.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.949+0000     schema:
     12:45:12.949+0000       label:
     12:45:12.949+0000         lucene:
     12:45:12.949+0000           write.lock: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 0.00 B
     12:45:12.950+0000           segments.gen: 2015-05-08T21:07:41+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.950+0000           segments_1: 2015-05-08T21:07:41+0000 - 32.00 B
     12:45:12.950+0000         - Total: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 52.00 B
     12:45:12.950+0000       - Total: 2015-05-07T22:38:10+0000 - 52.00 B
     12:45:12.950+0000     - Total: 2015-05-07T22:38:10+0000 - 52.00 B
     12:45:12.951+0000     neostore.nodestore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 239.87 kB
     12:45:12.951+0000     neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.951+0000     neostore.nodestore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.951+0000     neostore.nodestore.db.labels.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.952+0000     neostore.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.952+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.952+0000     neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 38.00 B
     12:45:12.952+0000     index:
     12:45:12.952+0000       lucene:
     12:45:12.953+0000         node:
     12:45:12.953+0000           postNode:
     12:45:12.953+0000             segments.gen: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.953+0000             _x74.nrm: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 3.24 kB
     12:45:12.954+0000             _x74.tis: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 178.98 kB
     12:45:12.954+0000             segments_3: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 299.00 B
     12:45:12.954+0000             _x74.fdx: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 25.88 kB
     12:45:12.954+0000             _x74.fdt: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 451.29 kB
     12:45:12.954+0000             _x74.tii: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 2.34 kB
     12:45:12.955+0000             _x74.frq: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 68.62 kB
     12:45:12.955+0000             _x74.fnm: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 322.00 B
     12:45:12.955+0000             _x74.prx: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 44.24 kB
     12:45:12.955+0000           - Total: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 775.21 kB
     12:45:12.955+0000           eventNode:
     12:45:12.956+0000             segments.gen: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.956+0000             _d8.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 690.00 B
     12:45:12.956+0000             _cr.fdt: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 4.19 kB
     12:45:12.956+0000             _cr.frq: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 96.00 B
     12:45:12.956+0000             _cr.fdx: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 108.00 B
     12:45:12.957+0000             _cz.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 716.00 B
     12:45:12.957+0000             _cw.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 716.00 B
     12:45:12.957+0000             _cr_1.del: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 32.00 B
     12:45:12.957+0000             _d2.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 716.00 B
     12:45:12.957+0000             _cr.prx: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 456.00 B
     12:45:12.958+0000             _cr.tis: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 738.00 B
     12:45:12.958+0000             _d5.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 692.00 B
     12:45:12.958+0000             _cr.tii: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 35.00 B
     12:45:12.958+0000             _ct.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 700.00 B
     12:45:12.958+0000             _cr.nrm: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 17.00 B
     12:45:12.959+0000             _cr.fnm: 2015-05-09T11:20:27+0000 - 65.00 B
     12:45:12.959+0000             segments_1: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 1.63 kB
     12:45:12.959+0000           - Total: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 11.48 kB
     12:45:12.959+0000           customerNode:
     12:45:12.959+0000             segments.gen: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.960+0000             segments_2: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 1.19 kB
     12:45:12.960+0000             _c4y.frq: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 66.83 kB
     12:45:12.960+0000             _c4y.fdx: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 110.61 kB
     12:45:12.960+0000             _c4y.tii: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 6.34 kB
     12:45:12.960+0000             _c4y.fnm: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 24.00 B
     12:45:12.961+0000             _c4y.prx: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 27.65 kB
     12:45:12.961+0000             _c4y.tis: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 640.17 kB
     12:45:12.961+0000             _c4y.nrm: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 13.83 kB
     12:45:12.961+0000             _c4y.fdt: 2015-05-09T12:43:53+0000 - 657.14 kB
     12:45:12.961+0000             _c50.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:08+0000 - 319.00 B
     12:45:12.962+0000             _c4z.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:07+0000 - 319.00 B
     12:45:12.962+0000             _c51.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:15+0000 - 319.00 B
     12:45:12.962+0000             _c52.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 319.00 B
     12:45:12.962+0000           - Total: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 1.49 MB
     12:45:12.962+0000           node_auto_index:
     12:45:12.963+0000             segments.gen: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.963+0000             segments_2: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 990.00 B
     12:45:12.963+0000             _16au.prx: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 58.00 kB
     12:45:12.963+0000             _16au.tis: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 755.05 kB
     12:45:12.964+0000             _16au_1.del: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 39.00 B
     12:45:12.964+0000             _16av.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:16+0000 - 865.00 B
     12:45:12.964+0000             _16au.fdt: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 931.55 kB
     12:45:12.964+0000             _16ax.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:23+0000 - 655.00 B
     12:45:12.964+0000             _16au.fdx: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 136.88 kB
     12:45:12.965+0000             _16au.frq: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 129.10 kB
     12:45:12.965+0000             _16au.tii: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 7.82 kB
     12:45:12.965+0000             _16aw.cfs: 2015-05-09T12:44:20+0000 - 826.00 B
     12:45:12.965+0000             _16au.nrm: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 17.11 kB
     12:45:12.965+0000             _16au.fnm: 2015-05-09T12:44:09+0000 - 360.00 B
     12:45:12.966+0000           - Total: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 1.99 MB
     12:45:12.966+0000           movieNode:
     12:45:12.966+0000             _wv.tis: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 1.01 kB
     12:45:12.966+0000             segments.gen: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 20.00 B
     12:45:12.966+0000             _wx.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 884.00 B
     12:45:12.967+0000             _wv_1.del: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 35.00 B
     12:45:12.967+0000             _wv.fdx: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 268.00 B
     12:45:12.967+0000             _wv.fnm: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 43.00 B
     12:45:12.967+0000             _wv.frq: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 306.00 B
     12:45:12.967+0000             _xi.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:31+0000 - 560.00 B
     12:45:12.968+0000             _wv.tii: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 35.00 B
     12:45:12.968+0000             _x9.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 330.00 B
     12:45:12.968+0000             _xf.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:26+0000 - 824.00 B
     12:45:12.968+0000             _wv.nrm: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 37.00 B
     12:45:12.968+0000             _xc.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 704.00 B
     12:45:12.969+0000             _x3.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 608.00 B
     12:45:12.969+0000             _wv.prx: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 1.12 kB
     12:45:12.969+0000             _x0.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 764.00 B
     12:45:12.969+0000             _x6.cfs: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 678.00 B
     12:45:12.969+0000             _wv.fdt: 2015-05-09T11:20:25+0000 - 9.86 kB
     12:45:12.969+0000             segments_1: 2015-05-09T12:36:03+0000 - 2.07 kB
     12:45:12.970+0000           - Total: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 20.02 kB
     12:45:12.970+0000         - Total: 2015-05-07T22:38:23+0000 - 4.27 MB
     12:45:12.970+0000       - Total: 2015-05-07T22:38:17+0000 - 4.27 MB
     12:45:12.970+0000       lucene.log.active: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 4.00 B
     12:45:12.970+0000       lucene-store.db: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 40.00 B
     12:45:12.971+0000       lucene.log.1: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 16.00 B
     12:45:12.971+0000     - Total: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 4.27 MB
     12:45:12.971+0000     neostore.labeltokenstore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.971+0000     lock: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 0.00 B
     12:45:12.971+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 1.63 kB
     12:45:12.972+0000     neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.972+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.index: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 387.00 B
     12:45:12.972+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.972+0000     store_lock: 2015-05-07T22:38:10+0000 - 0.00 B
     12:45:12.972+0000     neostore.labeltokenstore.db.names.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.973+0000     messages.log: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 159.00 kB
     12:45:12.973+0000     nioneo_logical.log.v2: 2015-05-09T12:44:36+0000 - 38.18 kB
     12:45:12.973+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.strings: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 13.25 kB
     12:45:12.973+0000     neostore.relationshipstore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 680.14 kB
     12:45:12.973+0000     neostore.relationshiptypestore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 5.00 B
     12:45:12.974+0000     neostore.schemastore.db: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 64.00 B
     12:45:12.974+0000     nioneo_logical.log.1: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 16.00 B
     12:45:12.974+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.arrays: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 128.00 B
     12:45:12.974+0000     neostore: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 63.00 B
     12:45:12.974+0000     nioneo_logical.log.active: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 4.00 B
     12:45:12.975+0000     neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.id: 2015-05-09T12:45:12+0000 - 9.00 B
     12:45:12.975+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles END ---
     12:45:12.996+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor started. 
     12:45:13.007+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Database is now ready
     12:45:13.007+0000   --- SERVER STARTED START ---
     12:45:13.470+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for org.neo4j.server.configuration.Configurator START ---
     12:45:13.471+0000   Server configuration:
     12:45:13.471+0000   org.neo4j.server.database.location = data/graph.db
     12:45:13.471+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.address = 0.0.0.0
     12:45:13.471+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.port = 80
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled = true
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port = 7473
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location = conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location = conf/ssl/snakeoil.key
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location = data/keystore
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location = data/rrd
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties = conf/neo4j.properties
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines = shell
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled = false
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.http.log.config = conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri = /db/manage/
     12:45:13.472+0000   org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri = /db/data/
     12:45:13.472+0000   --- STARTED diagnostics for org.neo4j.server.configuration.Configurator END ---
     12:45:13.475+0000   Mounted discovery module (org.neo4j.server.rest.discovery) at: /
     12:45:13.480+0000   Mounted REST API at: /db/data/
     12:45:13.481+0000   Mounted management API at: /db/manage/
     12:45:13.482+0000   Mounted webadmin at: /webadmin
     12:45:13.482+0000   Mounted Neo4j Browser at: /browser
     12:45:14.510+0000   Server started on: http://0.0.0.0/
     12:45:14.510+0000   --- SERVER STARTED END ---
     15:16:33.125+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 108ms [total block time: 0.108s]
     16:11:13.761+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 643ms [total block time: 0.751s]
     16:50:04.711+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 173ms [total block time: 0.924s]
     17:23:31.160+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 192ms [total block time: 1.116s]
     19:20:57.115+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 203ms [total block time: 1.319s]
     20:48:50.908+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 663ms [total block time: 1.982s]
     22:33:28.689+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 105ms [total block time: 2.087s]
     23:35:21.103+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 157ms [total block time: 2.244s]
     23:35:47.015+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 164ms [total block time: 2.408s]
     23:36:11.302+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 536ms [total block time: 2.944s]
     23:54:48.796+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 232ms [total block time: 3.176s]
     23:55:32.050+0000 WARN  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 185ms [total block time: 3.361s]
```

Would appreciate any guidance in this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: What is in those nodes that they're getting to 50MB each?  Are you trying to store binary files in there?